# Equation of a line with equal $x$ and $y$ coordinates in the form $Ax + By + C$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to rearrange a number of different equations of a line into the format ${Ax + By + C}$.

I can answer all but one which asks:

> formed by the set of points with equal x- and y- coordinates.

The answer is ${x - y = 0}$ but I don't understand how this answer was obtained.

Comment: Equal $x$ and $y$ coordinates means $x=y$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model line equation has an implicit righthand side "$=0$". Converting to this model a point set with identical $x$ and $y$ coordinates, i.e. $x=y$, only requires subtracting $y$ from both sides of the latter equation.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a set. Then your line will be the set of points $L = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb R ^2  : a = b\}$. Then one can see that this is actually the set of all the zeroes of the polynomial $x - y = 0$.